# Modifying Transaction Raw Data Before or After It Reaches MetaMask for Signing: Exploring Possibilities?"

Tags: ethereum, polygon, metamask

I'm developing a dApp interacting with a smart contract on Polygon. Users need to approve contract function executions in their wallets, usually MetaMask.

I'm curious if there's a way for users to modify the transaction's raw data (like function data) before signing and sending it. Are there any browser extensions, open-source wallets, or features like MetaMask Snaps that enable this functionality?

Essentially, we're exploring whether a user can modify the transaction's raw data after we've initiated it and it's been sent to their wallet for signing

thanks for any idea!